# Elegir en un formulario a que BD enviar los datos

Tags: php, mysql

Breve explicación: Tengo un formulario donde cargo usuarios en `MySQL` para que puedan acceder a la web. El tema es que la empresa en la que estoy, solicita separar la web por provincia. Entonces, tal provincia va a tener acceso a la web, desde su servidor, etc. Como administrador quiero tener 1 solo dashboard y poder cargar los usuarios y enviarlos al `MySQL` que corresponde. Hay forma de hacer eso? muestro mi código:

conexion:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "ac_prueba";
$username = "root";
$password = "*****";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

FORM:

```
   <form  method="POST" action="../../Usuarios/carga_user.php" >
   <table style="auto">
   <tr>
   <td class="td">
   <input class="input_user" type='text' maxlength="15" name="usuario" value="" placeholder="USUARIO" required autocomplete='off' />
     </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="td">
      <select class="input_user" name="region" required>
      <option value="" selected="selected"> - selecccionar region - </option>
      <option value="Administrador/AdminYPF/">Dashboard - Administrador</option>
      <option value="Personal/dashboard_usuarios/gnoc.php">NQN - GNOC</option>
      <option value="Personal/dashboard_usuarios/rdls.php">NQN - RDLS</option>
      <option value="Personal/dashboard_usuarios/ph.php">NQN - PH</option>
         </select>
           </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td class="td">
         <select class="input_user" name="permisos" required>
         <option value="" selected="selected" required> - selecccionar permiso - </option>
         <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>
         <option value="Estandar">Estandar</option>
         </select>
           </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
         <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_3" >REGISTRAR</button>
       </form>
```

Lo que pensé es que a lo mejor se pueda poner un `<select>`, o algo parecido. Agradeceré cualquier ayuda, para guiarme. Gracias

Comment: Diferentes tablas o bases de datos? No te sale mejor tener todo en una sola DB y marcada por algún código o ID por cada provincia o región?

Comment: En mi humilde opinión, tener una base de datos por cada provincia complica mucho las cosas. ¿No sería mejor añadir una columna provincia a las tablas que hagan falta?

Comment: diferentes BD, si tener una sola BD me soluciona todo, pero decisión de la compañía tenerlo asi, les gusta complicarme todo jaj

Comment: ya que demas datos que muestra la web, van a estar separados por provincia. Por si hay un problema, no caiga en todo el pais.

Comment: entonces, estoy buscando la vuelta para no tener que hacer varios dashboard, sino uno solo donde administro todo

Comment: "separar la web por provincia" no significa tener una base de datos por provincia. Tendrás también un servidor de mysql por cada provincia. Porque si el servidor se cae, se cae todo el país. Y tendrás también varios servidores web, uno por cada provincia. Porque si se cae el servidor web se cae todo el país.

Comment: claro, base de datos por provincia, me refiero a un servidor de MySQL por provincia. Lo exprese mal

Comment: Un servidor por provincia es un hosting tambien aparte. Tienes que hablar con tus contratantes y hacerlo como debe ser. Un solo servidor, una sola base de datos y tu ingenio como programador para diseñar la estructura en MySql que sea **escalable** ya que si por alguna razon te ordenan detener x provincia, con un solo click puedas hacerlo, o en el peor de los casos te botan de ese empleo, el que te sustituya sepa entender la estructura. _No ese arroz con mango que quieres_ hacer

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices Jefferson, como dije, tener todo en uno solo, es lo mejor.. Pero la compañía lo quiere hacer diferente. Ya se como hacerlo luego de pensarlo por varios minutos. Agradezco consejos

Comment: No es que haya reticencia de ayudar, es que eso va contra las lógicas del diseño. Si son 15 prov tendrás que pagar 15 hostings. Después te van a pedir que cuando se actualice X registro, también aparezca en las otras BD; o unificar 2 BD de provincias con poco tráfico, etc... Cuando la empresa no sabe lo que está solicitando, se complica ella misma y a los demás. Creo que más que una respuesta, necesita asesoría de expertos en la materia.

Comment: 15 provincias.. 15 bases de datos.. ojala no tengas que cambiar una columna porque significa que tenes que hacer 15 alter en 15 lados diferentes... no.. no esta bien... salvo que esto sea on premises, es una mala idea.... y con respecto a hacerlo, necesitas una base maestra que te diga a que base tenes que ir...

Comment: Hasta donde dice: *la empresa en la que estoy, solicita separar la web por provincia*, todo OK, no hay ningún problema. Pero ¿te pidieron también explícitamente que crees `N` base de datos, donde `N` es el total de provincias? Y ya lo de `N` hostings es una locura. Si te han pedido eso, tendría que haber una razón muy poderosa que lo justifique. Sea como sea, por lo general el cliente no tiene ni idea de lo que está ocurriendo en el servidor y lo propio en este caso es montar todo en un mismo servidor y en una única base de datos. Lo de las URLs por provincia y demás es lo de menos.

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo en cuenta que tenemos el `cliente` (El dashboard) y un servidores por provincia, y queremos crear usuarios eligiendo el servidor. podrías hacer una [API REST](https://platzi.com/clases/1638-api-rest/21611-que-significa-rest-y-que-es-una-api-restful/) por servidor de cada provincia.

Un [API REST](https://platzi.com/clases/1638-api-rest/21611-que-significa-rest-y-que-es-una-api-restful/) sirve para comunicar un cliente con un servidor mediante solicitudes `HTTP`, de esta forma podemos hacer las operaciones de un `CRUD`.

En tu caso, vas a comunicarte con muchos servidores, es ideal mantener cierto orden con las `url` de cada servidor, esto con el fin de poder realizar la solicitudes de una forma mas prolija, por ejemplo:

```
https://compañia.provincia.algo
```

De esta manera se te facilitara mas a la hora de realizar las solicitudes, solo tendrías que remplazar `provincia` en `url` por una abreviatura para esta provincia, esto con el fin de seguir teniendo un orden, y acá pueden entrar en juego los `select` que mencionabas, por ejemplo:

```
<select id="provincias">
    <option value="pr1">Provincia 1</option>
    <option value="pr2">Provincia 2</option>
    <option value="pr3">Provincia 3</option>
</select>
```

Después recuperando el valor del `select`, deberías añadir a la `url` remplazando `provincia` y quedaría así en el caso de seleccionar `Provincia 2`:

```
https://compañia.pr2.algo
```

Para hacer la parte del lado servidor podes usar algún framework como [Slim Framework](https://www.slimframework.com/) o lo que sepas usar.

Después no queres que nadie mas que no sea el `admin` utilice el `API REST`, debes hacer algún tipo de autenticación como [JWT](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) para proteger el `API REST`.

Comment: Al crear subdominios podés emular los servidores, pero igual debería crear N bases de datos y los hosting que te lo permitan cuesta dinero. Otro punto a tener en cuenta es que las peticiones API REST quedarían vulnerables a menos que compres N certificados SSL y configurar muy bien las políticas CORS. Los hay gratis pero solo por 90 días. En fin @Matias tendrás mucho trabajo que hacer y espero te paguen muy bien ese servicio.